# Testbench of a Mux 4x1 using Verilog

Tags: verilog

I am trying to use a testbench to test some features of a 4X1 Mux [a,b,c,d are the inputs , z is the output and s is the select line]. Here is my code:

```
module testbench_MUX();



  reg a,b,c,d;

  reg [1:0] s;

  wire z ; 


  MUX4_1 mux(.a(a) ,.b(b),.c(c),.d(d), .s(s),.z(z));


  initial begin 
    $dumpfile("dump.vcd");
    $dumpvars;
  end 

initial begin // {
     a='b0;b='b1 ;c='b0 ;d='b1 ;s='d0;#15
    if(z==0) $display("time : %0t Test # 1 : passed",$time);
    a='b0;b='b1 ;c='b0 ;d='b1 ;s='d1;#15
    if(z==1) $display("Test # 2 : passed");
    a='b0;b='b0 ;c='b1 ;d='b1 ;s='d1; #15
    if(z==0) $display("Test # 3 : passed");
    a='b1;b='b0 ;c='b0 ;d='b0 ;s='d1; #15
    if(z==0) $display("Test # 4 : passed");

    $finish;
    end // }
```

Here is the waveform:

[image]

The kernel displays that test 1 has passed, meaning that z=0:

```
# KERNEL: time : 15Test # 1 : passed
```

But, as you can see from the waveform at time 15ns (the simulation timescale is 1ns/1ns), z=1.  Why does the `if` statement execute?

MUX designcode :

```
module MUX4_1(
  input  a,b,c,d, 
  input   [1:0] s,
  output reg  z

);
  always @ (*) begin
    if ( s==0) 
      z=a;

    else if ( s==1) 
      z=b;

    else if ( s==2) 
      z=c;
    else if (s==3)

      z=d;

    else  
      z=a;

  end 

endmodule: MUX4_1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a race condition.  At time 15, you change the `s` input, which causes a change on the `z` output from 0 to 1.  At the same time you sample the `z` output (`if(z=0)`).  The simulator sees `z` at 0.

You should delay the time at which you change the input, so that you sample the output when you know it will be stable.  For example:

```
initial begin
    a='b0; b='b1 ; c='b0 ; d='b1  ;s='d0;
    #15
    if(z==0) $display("time : %0t Test # 1 : passed",$time);
    #1;

    a='b0;b='b1 ;c='b0 ;d='b1 ;s='d1;
```

In this case, `z` will be checked at time 15, and then `s` will change at time 16.